# JMeter - Loop for X time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a test script where I want the test to (1) Log into application (2) Do some stuff repeatedly for x time (ideally 15 minutes) and (3) log out of application.  I have setup step 2 to use Loop Controller, but I find the only way to get the run time of the test to 15 minutes is to play with the Loop Controller's "Loop Count" variable until the run time reaches near 15 minutes.  But I'd like to be able to just say "loop for 15 minutes, then end loop and log out".  How can this be accomplished, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is putting your logic under the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) instead of the Loop Controller.

---

Another possible option is [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) where you can define multiple conditions like `exit the loop after 1000 iterations or 15 minutes, whatever comes the first`

Comment: So...
Login Samplers, Runtime Controller (set to 900 seconds), Loop Controller as a child of Runtime Controller (set to infinite / some number of loops greater than it would take for 15 mins), Logoff Samplers

?

Comment: "instead" means that you should replace Loop Controller with Runtime Controller